# Very bad response time with solr ShingleFilterFactory field faceting

Tags: solr, lucene

I use solr `ShingleFilterFactory` to suggest words while typing. It works fine. However, the first query is very long (about **30 seconds** with 600,000 documents). Worse still, **every soft commit** it happens again (every hard commit too, off course). Just as if the full index had to be reloaded from the disk, just to compute this particular facet.

Here is the configuration of my index:

```
<fieldType name="textSpellShingle" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,;.^*!?|]"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="6" outputUnigrams="true"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern="[\s,;.^*!?|]"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

My Solr version is 4.2.0

It doesn't seem to be related to `facet.prefix` since even a simple query facet on my Shingle  field causes the problem.
How can I improve the response time and if possible do not suffer every soft commit ?

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Do you have spellcheck.build=true in your query?